# Second order all-pass filter input impedance

Tags: analog, ltspice, active-filter, input-impedance

I have a question about the second order all-pass filter input impedance when ω = ∞ and ω = 0 and I would appreciate if you could help me to understand the logic.

1. When ω = 0, all capacitors can be seen as open circuit, because we are at DC level. In this case I expect the Zin to be R3+R4, what would be 3 kOhms, because the voltage at opamp inputs would be 0V. From the simulation I see that the expected input impedance is 1.5 kOhms. Why?
2. When ω = ∞, capacitors can be seen as short circuits, and therefore the current will travel along C with no electrical impedance and R3, R4 are the only impedances that separates V1 from ground. In this case I do not understand why the input impedance is 3 kOhms.

Thank you in advance!
[image: Input impedance simulation]

[image: Circuit setup]

Comment: At DC imagine opening circuits for all C’s  Then V1 only sees R3+R4 and that’s what the green line shows at 1 Hz.  What is confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At DC \$\omega = 0\$ (all capacitors can be seen as open circuit) we have this situation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhizlB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And $$R_{IN_{DC}} = R_3 + R_4 = 3k\Omega $$

But at high frequency (\$\omega = ∞\$) when all capacitors can be seen as short circuits we have this situation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRpKps.png)</sup>

Therefore the input resistance is now equal to:

$$R_{IN_{HF}} = \left[R_1 \times\left(1 + \frac{R_4}{R_3}\right)\right]||(R_3+R_4) = 3k\Omega||3k\Omega = 1.5k\Omega$$

Why? because now the voltage across \$R_1\$ resistor is no longer equal to \$V_{IN}\$ but to the difference between \$V_{IN}\$ and op-amp output voltage. 
And the op-amp is working as a voltage follower, meaning that the op-amp output voltage is the same as the input voltage (at non-inverting input). And the input voltage is the output voltage produced by the voltage divider build around \$R_3, R_4\$.

Comment: Now it is very easy to understand. Thank you a lot for your explanation!

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a case of mistaken identity: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this mistake! I have apparently been really confused.

Comment: That's OK - it happens to all of us!